# Font-face does not work properly

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I downloaded "Bebas Neue" (legally from [dafont.com](http://dafont.com)).

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'BebasNeue';
    src: url('bebasneue-webfont-webfont.eot');
    src: url('bebasneue-webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('bebasneue-webfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('bebasneue-webfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('bebasneue-webfont-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I used the font squirrel [webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) for this. I don't understand why this only works locally (on Chrome) but nowhere else...

Any suggestions?

Comment: are the fonts served from the same domain as the website? and show the css where you assign the font

Comment: You might get more help if you explain what exactly doesn't work?  What happens?

Comment: check that fonts are placed in same directory of your css code

Comment: The answer to the first question is Yes, but on the other PC or Browser it doesn't show as Bebas Neue but totally change in another font...

Comment: I don't know if it depends by the fact I'm using WP but it's so strange... It always worked! Anyway the fonts are in the same directory of the stylesheets.

Comment: On Chrome and Opera it works fine anyway, the problem is IE and FF. But on other pc it does not work!